# What is '#' in Dapper examples?

Tags: sql, dapper

I'm learning Dapper through [code.google](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) and [github](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net). I noticed that some table names have '#' as prefix. I tried using '#', but it's not working, I got an error saying that I have error in my SQL syntax. What's the meaning of '#' in the examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL-Server, `#tablename` denotes a temporary table (which can be connection-based, or local to a stored-procedure). `##tablename` denotes a global temporary table. There is also `@tablename` which is a table-variable (or can also be a parameter, variable, or table-valued-parameter).

Comment: At first, I thought it has something to do with the mapping.